# Can't connect my ESP-12F to WiFi with my Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, communication, wireless

Recently I bought this wifi adapter for my IOT projects that I connected to my arduino uno that seems to not working. 
I have tried with the arduino ESP8266WiFi library with RX connected to pin 0 and TX connected to pin 1 I have also tried the softwareSerial and still the same result that is, in the serial monitor i always get "*error*" or I get nothing 
Thank you in advance and sorry if I made a mistake in the post, I am new to StackExchange :)

edit (added code to question):

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial ESPSerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  // if this doesnt work you for you then try different baud rate
  ESPSerial.begin(115200);
  ESPSerial.println("Ready to take AT commands");
}

void loop() { // run over and over
  if (ESPSerial.available()) {
    // reads input from serial console and writes to esp8266
    Serial.write(ESPSerial.read());
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    // reads input from esp8266 and writes to serial console
    ESPSerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

[image: Esp adapter]

[image: error]

Comment: Please add your source code as text to your post and what is your expected output? Also please tell us for which board the shown code is.

Comment: did you set in Serial Monitor the line ends?

Comment: @TarickWelling I am using arduino uno and I was expecting to enter some at commands.

Comment: gpo0 goes to ground to program the module